# Sql query does not bring more than 4 results in a for loop in C#

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, datagridview, connection

This code just works looping from 0 to 3. When I increase the variable i to 4 or more it does not bring results. I have almost 700 descriptions to be queried. How can I do that? Here's my code. Thank you,

```
SqlCommandBuilder myBuilder;
DataSet mySet;
DataTable myTable;
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
SqlCommand myCommand = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str = "";
    int specRowCount = dataGridView2.Rows.Count;

    mySet = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
           str = "use " + textBox4.Text + " SELECT * FROM myTable where myRule=1 and myFlag=1 and description='" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";
            //myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConnection);
            myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(str, myConnection);
            //myBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(myAdapter);

            myAdapter.Fill(mySet, "t_rules");  
        }
        myTable = mySet.Tables["t_rules"];
        myConnection.Close();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = mySet.Tables["t_rules"];

        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }  
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, I'd fix that first.

Comment: Just a side note, this is clearly not a console application but the catch is writing to the console.

Comment: 1) Setting a fixed size for your loop is not a good idea. It should be based on grid rows (if you stick with that route). 2) If any of your [Description] values contain apostrophes ('), you will get an error. 3) every iteration through your loop, you are overwriting your dataset when you call myAdapter.Fill(mySet, "t_rules"). So re-querying within a loop is going to beat up your DB.  You should only run the last query, because that is the only result set that you are keeping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Grant Thomas and @Paulie Waulie are right.  The problem is (probably) because you have an apostrophe in the [description] on row 3 of dataGridView2.  It is throwing an error, you are catching it and not seeing it.  Try putting a messagebox or breakpoint in your catch block and you will see.

To fix your query, try this:

```
str = "use " + textBox4.Text + "; SELECT * FROM myTable 
where myRule=1 and myFlag=1 and [description]='" + 
Replace(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),"'","''") + "'";
```

Comment: Thank you guys! apostroph problem!!! following code worked out! Thank you Golisch!

`cleanDesc =` `dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Replace("'","''");`
`str = "use " + textBox4.Text + " SELECT * FROM t_rules where` `ruletype=1 and currentflag=1 and description='" + cleanDesc + "'";`

Answer (score 0):

The only way this code couldn't return any more results when increasing the counter, is for the `SELECT` statement to return zero rows. The query is excluding the additional row you're querying for some reason.

Increase the counter to 700, and you may or may not get more data, it depends on what this query returns.

But at the end of the day, the query is returning zero rows.